# gfortran IEEE exception inexact

Tags: exception, floating-point, fortran, gfortran

We are using gfortran (5.3.1), Fedora 23, in a new 64 b machine. Compiling with simple gfortran -o (we are not using -ffpe-trap options !), excites the "classical- trivial" warning:

```
Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_INVALID_FLAG
```

Its due to INEXACT exception (type 2.0/3.0). The DDD debugger points towards a  real constant (180d0/pi; pi = 3.141518...). We don't understand why this flag appears, with this basic compilation, because these exceptions are reached all the time...

Some code here:

```
    Implicit none !real*8(a-h,o-z)   
    real*8 pi,dpi,radgra,TSI,TOL,xlsol,fi,W      
    Integer year, T1, k,m

      open(10,file='stof-elem.sol') 

          pi = 4.d0 * datan(1.d0)
         dpi = 2.d0 * pi
       radgra = 360.d0 / dpi !!!!!!!! HERE POINTS THE EXCEPTION!!!!!!!!!!

         T1 = -9998 !800d0 !1450d0 !

        TSI = 1360.d0 !1364.5d0 !1367d0 

        TOL = 0.7d0 / radgra ! dont' use smaller 

C...Name of the output file
      open(12,file='midmonth-2000.sal')

C-----------------------------------------------------------------------
            k = 0 ! outputs counter

            write(12,*)T1            

      DO m = 1, 12  ! select month
           IF(T1.lt.0) then
             xlsol = (270.d0 - dble(m-1) * 30.d0) / radgra !from Dec
               if(xlsol.lt.0d0) xlsol = xlsol + dpi
           ELSE
              xlsol = dble(m-3) * 30.d0 / radgra !from Jan
               if(xlsol.lt.0d0) xlsol = xlsol + dpi
           ENDIF 

            CALL MEANINSOLA(pi,dpi,radgra,TOL,T1,TSI,xlsol,fi,k,W)

            rewind(10) ! better rewind...
      ENDDO

       write(*,*) 'Outputs:', k,'lines'
```

The EXCEPTION appears at the definition of RADGRA ... as indicated. If redefine the constant (i.e.,, RADGRA = 57.2d0), the exception migrates to another parts using RADGRA... and so on...

Comment: Show *at least* the commands that caused this note to be printed. You should also show some code sample http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please show the **full compilation command** as I asked. Do you use `stop` before your `end`? If yes, don't do that. Report also your gfortran version and full code including the `end program`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/fortran/2013-06/msg00072.html the Fortran standard requires printing of these notes after executing the `STOP` statement.

> "If any exception (14) is signaling on that image, the processor shall
>   issue a warning indicating which exceptions are signaling; this
>   warning shall be on the unit identified by the named constant ERROR
>   UNIT (13.8.2.8)."

Note that even if you request the Fortran 95 standard by `-std=f95` the note is still displayed.

You can control this behaviour by `-ffpe-summary=`, consult you compiler's [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Debugging-Options.html). By default, a summary for all exceptions but ‘inexact’ is shown.  Have you enabled inexact yourself somewhere?

Why is that exception signalling is a different matter, you must examine your code whether it is something you should be worried about or not. Probably you should not, inexact floating point operations are **very common**.

Because the message is invoked by the `STOP` statement, a simple way to get rid of these messages is to not terminate your program by a `STOP` statement, but let it reach the `END PROGRAM`.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir F. The outputs are OK ... and the same definitions and code parts are used in another codes with normal compilation and excitation... so; something is not going fine with another code part?

Comment: Please show the **full compilation command** as I asked. The note is probably something you should *not* be worried about, signalling inexact is common, **very common** in fact.

Comment: As I said, using gfortran 5.3.1. with simple compilation: gfortran -o mp.e mp.for. By the way, is standard F77.... Yes, it has STOP, before the END

Comment: Remove the stop -> warning goes away. It us **useless** to have a stop before the end. The code is F77, but the compiler compiles it as F2008. You may try to change to -std=f95, if it changes something (probably not).