# Floating-point exceptions using gfortran for Fortran 77

Tags: linux, fortran, precision, gfortran, fortran77

I am using gfortran on Ubuntu 16.04 to compile a main file and a bunch of subroutine files written in Fortran 77. They are compiled without any error or warning but after running the executable file, I get "zero" and "NaN" everywhere in the result which is unexpected according to the released output of the original code.

After running the exe I get this note:

> "Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_INVALID_FLAG IEEE_DENORMAL"

I also used the following flags in my makefile but they didn't make any difference:

```
FCFLAGS= -c -g -fbacktrace -ffpe-trap=zero,overflow,underflow
```

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve]. We need to see the code to see why it returns zeros and NaNs. Regarding the `EEE_INVALID_FLAG IEEE_DENORMAL` note, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44308577/ieee-underflow-flag-ieee-denormal-in-fortran-77 it is not very important message for you.

Comment: Also, I *seriously* doubt you are actually using fortran 77. More likely, your file extension is `.f77` or `.f`, which only means fixed form, the syntax of source files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IEEE\_UNDERFLOW\_FLAG IEEE\_DENORMAL in Fortran 77](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44308577/ieee-underflow-flag-ieee-denormal-in-fortran-77)

Comment: What is your concern?  You'll need to show us code for us to advise on what may be invalid operations, or where numbers become denormal.  Note, though, that in your `-ffpe-trap` list you haven't invald or denormal so I wouldn't expect the compiler to abort with those.

Comment: @agentp I have actually closed it as a duplicate of that function first. And then I re-opened, because it is not just about this note, but about the *"I get "zero" and "NaN" everywhere in the result"* which unfortunately cannot be answered without the relevant code. But not a duplicate in my opinion, that's why I re-opened.