# Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_UNDERFLOW_FLAG IEEE_DENORMAL

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran

now is the time, i am using a gfortran program. I get the error "Note: Signaling following comma exception: IEEE_UNDERFLOW_FLAG IEEE_DENORMAL".

I don't know how to fix it? Can you help me fix it? Edit where?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and always search if the question was already asked before. The question window is supposed to show you suggestions of previous questions to look at. Also, use the [tag:fortran] tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IEEE\_UNDERFLOW\_FLAG IEEE\_DENORMAL in Fortran 77](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44308577/ieee-underflow-flag-ieee-denormal-in-fortran-77) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35992992/gfortran-ieee-exception-inexact?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I would like to stress one thing, the message is a "**Note:**", it is NOT an error. For some reason your code called the `STOP` statement. We cannot tell you why.